# Ionic Js / Angular JS - Get an element inside a modal and set value

Tags: jquery, angularjs, modal-dialog, ionic-framework

Clicking on an external button i need to set a modal's internal element value. Both elements are inside different section, so they have different controllers, i need a way to pass the button value from `mainCtrl` to `modalCtrl`.

```
<div id="external-element" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <button ng-click="getValue($event)" data-value="1">Get this value</button>
</div>

<script id="modal.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <div id="modal-section" class="modal" ng-controller="modalCtrl">
        <p class="waiting-for-button-value"></p>
    </div>
</script>
```

After some researching i've find that this could be possibile by creating a service:

```
app.factory('dataShare',function($rootScope){
    var service = {};
    service.data = false;
    service.sendData = function(data){
        this.data = data;
        $rootScope.$broadcast('data_shared');
    };
    service.getData = function(){
        return this.data;
    };
    return service;
});
```

To let this data talk between my controllers i did this:

```
app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, dataShare, $ionicModal){
    $scope.getValue = function(event){
        var myValue = $(event.target).data('value');
        dataShare.sendData(myValue);
    };
}

app.controller('modalCtrl', function($scope, dataShare){
    $scope.$on('data_shared',function(){
        var text =  dataShare.getData();
        $('.waiting-for-a-new-value').html(text);
    });
});
```

If i've forget anything please accept my apologies, i'm really new to ionic/angularJs.

Comment: Did you have the chance to try my solution? Cheers.

Comment: hi my friend, sorry for the late! unfortunately no, the project has been paused temporarily, but your suggestions seems very interesting, i hope to watch for it in these days, anyway thank you so much!

Comment: No worries mate. I can understand we're all busy. Let me know how it goes. Saluti. Ciao.

Answer (score 1):

You really don't need to broadcast events if you want to communicate with a modal.
Modals can live in the view which calls them so they share the same scope.

Is there any particular reason why you're using `data-value="1"` and jQuery to pass around data?

angular gives has got this binding features which allow you to bind items/objects/values to every element in the DOM:

```
app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.myValue = "this is a value";
    $scope.myObject = {name: 'Luca'};
    };
}
```

which you can bind to a textbox using double-binding with `ng-model`:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myValue">
<input type="text" ng-model="myObject.name">
```

or single-binding:

```
<input type="text" value="{{myValue}}">
<input type="text" value="{{myObject.name}}">
```

with the double-binding the object in the `$scope` will be kept in sync, which means you will always be able to read the updated value.

Going back to your modal. Modals are created inside a controller so they technically can share the same scope.

You would do something like this to create a modal:

```
  $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('myModal.html', {
    scope: $scope,
    animation: 'slide-in-up'
  }).then(function(modal) {
    $scope.modal = modal;
  });
```

when the promise is resolved (`.then()`) the created modal is saved in the `$scope` so that it can be opened later simply calling `openModal`:

```
  $scope.openModal = function() {
    $scope.modal.show();
  };
```

As I said views and modals can share the same scope so your modal could look something like this:

```
<ion-modal-view>
    <ion-header-bar>
      <h1 class="title">I am a modal</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
      {{myObject.name}}
    </ion-content>
</ion-modal-view>
```

and show the value you have set in your `textbox` previousely:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myObject.name">
```

which would be updated instantly.

You can check this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9cpZMyDU2sVfsnblMI5N?p=preview). You can set the modal's title and body. When opening the modal with the button, your new modal will show the values you've inserted in the views.